# Filtering vector tile layer in OpenLayers map?

Tags: openlayers, geodjango, vector-tiles

I have GeoDjango application for the visualization of household data with around 10k features. So I have used the vector tile for the visualization of these data. Now I faced the problem with the proper way of filtering the datasets.

Though I get an idea of filtering datasets with style function it didn't help much and I don't think its best way approach, as data is not actually filtered in this scenario.

I have used following code for the visualization purpose:

```
  var urlFilter = '/api/v1/data/house.mvt?tile{z}/{x}/{y}';
  var vectorHouse = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
    declutter: true,
    // style:simpleStyle,
    source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
      // tilePixelRatio: 20, // oversampling when > 1
      tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({maxZoom: 24}),
      // projection: 'EPSG:3857',
      format: new ol.format.MVT(),
      url: urlFilter
    })
   });
   
  spatialMap.addLayer(vectorHouse);
```

Now I am looking for the client-side filter based upon the properties like houseID. I am using Django as backend and [djangorestframework-mvt](https://github.com/corteva/djangorestframework-mvt) for vector tile generation.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Filtering where? Server side or client side? How do you serve vector tiles? Which format?

Comment: Basically I am focussed on client-side. Though I am using Djangorestframework-mvt, it supports basic filter but it doesn't fully satisfy my requirements.

Comment: Please edit your question and add this additional info and also relevant existing code of what you have tried so far, otherwise question is most likely to be closed (see https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: okay thanks for suggestions I have edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way to filter `MVT` vector tile layer on the client side would be to use layer `style` option and set a style function that would set style only for selected features.

Below is a simple example of filtering only coastlines (based on official example at https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-tile-info.html):

```
var defaultStyles = new ol.layer.Vector().getStyleFunction()();

var styleFunction = function(feature, resolution) {
  if (feature.get('layer') == 'Coastline') {
    return(defaultStyles);
  }
};

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2,
  }),
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.VectorTile({
      source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
        format: new ol.format.MVT(),
        url: 'https://basemaps.arcgis.com/v1/arcgis/rest/services/World_Basemap/VectorTileServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.pbf',
      }),
      style: styleFunction
    })
  ],
});
```

Comment: The MVT format has a similar filter format: `new ol.format.MVT({layerName: 'layer', layers: ['Coastline']}),`

Comment: @Mike Yes, that's definitely even simpler when one wants only to apply filter, without changing the style.

Answer (score 2):

You can use filter in url or after download the data in following solution.

```
  var vectorHouse = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
    declutter: true,
    // style:simpleStyle,
    source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
      // tilePixelRatio: 20, // oversampling when > 1
      tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({maxZoom: 24}),
      // projection: 'EPSG:3857',
      loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {        
        $.ajax({
          url: "your filter data url",
          success: function(data) {
             
             /// you can filter data here
             
            var features = new ol.format.MVT().readFeatures(data);
            farmersSource.addFeatures(features);
          }
        }); 
      }
    })
   });
```

Comment: thanks got your idea and it helped to some extent